# how to group by every 6 hours in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i tried to search, but couldn't find anything. but i'm using postgresql, but i want to group by every 6 hours. so something similar to

`date_trunc('hour', start_date)`

but every 6 hours.

Comment: What format is your startdate? Can you leave an example?

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use the day and hour:

```
select date_trunc('day', start_date) + floor(extract(hour from start_date) / 6.0) * 6 * interval '1 hour' as yyyymmddhh6,
       count(*)
from t
group by yyyymmddhh6;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6e9f15eb19aaae1bba36f6947870a42a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: ty. sorry what would the * interval '1 hour' at the end do? it isn't running on my version of sql

Comment: I get this error when trying to * interval ' 1 hour'. DataConnectionError: Database returned error while executing query 
SQL compilation error: error line 7 at position 83
Invalid argument types for function '*': (NUMBER(10,0), INTERVAL)... is there another way for me to append the hour to the day?

Comment: @jc315 . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The code works as originally written.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [this](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/timestamp-date_trunc) generic function.

```sql
create or replace function interval_date_trunc
 (trunc_period interval, ts timestamptz, base_ts timestamptz default '1970-01-01Z')
 returns timestamptz language sql immutable as
$fn$
select
  base_ts
  + floor(extract(epoch from ts - base_ts) / extract(epoch from trunc_period))::bigint
  * trunc_period;
$fn$;
```

and then

```sql
select interval_date_trunc(interval '6 hours', start_date) as running_6h,
       count(*)
from t
group by running_6h;
```

The function can be used in other cases of running interval aggregation too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new answer because I think this approach suits your need better. In summary-- we are concatenating the range of hours to the date part of the start_date so that it's less confusing to the user when you show them the aggregated data

```
with cte (start_date) as

(select '2020-01-09 05:32:43' union all
 select '2020-01-09 17:32:43' union all
 select '2020-01-09 22:32:43' union all
 select '2020-01-09 21:32:43' union all
 select '2020-01-09 11:32:43')


select start_date,
       left(start_date,10) || 
       to_char(floor(extract(hour from start_date::timestamp)/6)*6,'00h -') ||
       to_char(ceil(extract(hour from start_date::timestamp)/6)*6,'00h') as start_date_group
from cte
```

**Outputs**

```
+---------------------+----------------------+
|     start_date      |   start_date_group   |
+---------------------+----------------------+
| 2020-01-09 05:32:43 | 2020-01-09 00h - 06h |
| 2020-01-09 17:32:43 | 2020-01-09 12h - 18h |
| 2020-01-09 22:32:43 | 2020-01-09 18h - 24h |
| 2020-01-09 21:32:43 | 2020-01-09 18h - 24h |
| 2020-01-09 11:32:43 | 2020-01-09 06h - 12h |
+---------------------+----------------------+
```